# JavaBinder and Orchestrator FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error after running certain JUnit tests

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm automating an Android app using Espresso. All of my tests technically run and execute as I expect them too; however, certain tests fail when the reach completion. At the end of a test execution, the following exception is thrown:

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1514656)
E/OrchestrationListener: Unable to send TestRunFinished Status to Orchestrator
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1514656 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1127)
at androidx.test.runner.internal.deps.aidl.BaseProxy.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(BaseProxy.java:65)
at androidx.test.orchestrator.callback.OrchestratorCallback$Stub$Proxy.sendTestNotification(OrchestratorCallback.java:95)
at androidx.test.orchestrator.instrumentationlistener.OrchestratedInstrumentationListener.sendTestNotification(OrchestratedInstrumentationListener.java:167)
at androidx.test.orchestrator.instrumentationlistener.OrchestratedInstrumentationListener.testRunFinished(OrchestratedInstrumentationListener.java:104)
at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testRunFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:42)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$2.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:103)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestRunFinished(RunNotifier.java:100)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
```

This execption comes from the `OrchestratedInstrumentationListen` class's `testRunFinished` method:

```
  @Override
  public void testRunFinished(Result result) {
    try {
      sendTestNotification(
          TestEvent.TEST_RUN_FINISHED, BundleJUnitUtils.getBundleFromResult(result));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Unable to send TestRunFinished Status to Orchestrator", e);
    }
  }
```

When investigating this error, I found many threads referencing the handling of images. I am using no images of any kind, and the only information being passed around is composed of string data. The only images I can think of are local resource assets I use instead of referencing the AWS S3 versions. But I use those image resources in my other 50 tests without an issue, so I'm doubtful of that being the cause.

I think that the status of the test results being passed to the Androidx Orchestrator is the `parcel` in this case, and being that it's about 1.5MB, I can see why the exception is thrown. But I'm unsure of how to decrease the size of the test results. Other tests with more steps do not encounter this issue, so I'm at a loss. I've seen some advice about removing Orchestrator altogether, but I need it to run the tests, as they rely on the app being in the same state at start and end.

Why is this happening and what would be the best solution?